# Showing a slide out menu across tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got this requirement where we have to have slide out menu for our app (left or right). However, I was querying if it would be possible to show the same slide out menu across tabs of the browser.

For example, when I load my app on "tab1", it loads the menu. Now, I opened another tab, "tab2", from the application (a link or button). Is it possible to show that same menu on the page that opened in "tab2", given that the page opened in "tab2" can be originating from anywhere on the Internet, i.e., I cannot code that page in "tab2".

I did some search over google and here but this particular issue is not queried anywhere. It would be awesome if you can tell about any possibility and then I can try to do some POC around it.

Regards,
Ankur

Comment: You could set a cookie everytime you open a slide. Whenever you load a new tab/page you read the cookie and open the proper slide.

Comment: But I cannot do anything on that next page. It's not controlled by me.

Comment: Without having control over the next page... no. Only if the next page has a control feature implemented.

Comment: ok. Thanks Gerfried. This means we cannot do this.